# Flutter extract async to separator class and methods

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

[My implementation repository](https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/Floor-Sample)

in `main` method i have this lines of code to connect to database and work fine

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final database = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();

  final userDao = database.userDao;

  runApp(MaterialApp(...);
}
```

now i'm trying to use this codes

```dart
  final database = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
  final userDao = database.userDao;
```

from class, for example:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  MyDatabase myDatabase = MyDatabase();
  final userDao = myDatabase.userDao;

  runApp(MaterialApp(...);
}
```

unfortunately i get `null` for `userDao` in this implementation, i think in that witch i use `async` i should be change that and use `then()`

```dart
class MyDatabase {
  UserDao userDao;

  Future<UserDao> initialDatabase() async {
    final database = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
    return database.userDao;
  }
}

@dao
abstract class UserDao{
  @Query('SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1')
  Stream<User> getUserInfo();

  @insert
  Future<void> insertUserInformation(User user);
}
```

**UPDATED: implementation solution on scope model**

```
class MydbModel extends Model {
  MyDatabase myDatabase = MyDatabase();
  Future _doneFuture;

  MydbModel()  {
    _doneFuture= myDatabase.initialDatabase();
  }

  Future get initializationDone => _doneFuture;
}

class MyDatabase {
  AppDatabase db;
  UserDao userDao;

  Future<void> initialDatabase() async {
    db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
  }

  UserDao getUserDao() {
    return db.userDao;
  }
}

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'floor sample',
    home: App(),
  ));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  App({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ScopedModel(
        model: MydbModel(),
        child: ScopedModelDescendant<MydbModel>(
          builder: (context, _, model) => StreamBuilder<User>(
            stream: model.myDatabase.userDao.getUserInfo(),
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('user not found');
              } else {
                return Text('user found');
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With given class implementation, you should call the function and wait until it completes:

```
MyDatabase myDatabase = MyDatabase();
final userDao = await myDatabase.initialDatabase();
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to recreate databse instance each time, consider assigning it to a class member

```
class MyDatabase {
  AppDatabase db;

  Future<void> initDb() async {
    db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
  }

  UserDao getUserDao() {
    return db.userDao;
  }

  // here may be other functions that use db
}
```

And the use it like this

```
MyDatabase myDatabase = MyDatabase();
await myDatabase.initDb();
final userDao = myDatabase.getUserDao();
// here you can call other functions from class
```

Comment: could you take a sample to know how can i wait to complete? my mean is your first introduced solution

Comment: Just two lines that I wrote in my answer